# Rake task not calling the worker job in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I have defined a rake task and a worker job using sidekiq as below. The rake task is not calling the worker job. Please help me find my problem.

Office.rake

```
namespace :office do
  desc "send reminder emails"
  task send_reminder: :environment do
    Office.all.each do |office|
      (office.issues.includes(:billings).where("issues.api_accounts_receivable > 0").select { |issue| (issue.billings.last.date < Message.last.date) if issue.billings.present? }).each do |issue|
        puts "Issue ID is #{issue["id"]}"
        ReminderWorker.perform_async("#{issue["id"]}")  
      end
    end
  end
end
```

reminder_worker.rb

```
class ReminderWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform(issue_id)
    puts issue_id
  end
end
```

puts don't show output for issue_id in the terminal for the worker but does show output for **"Issue ID is #{issue["id"]}"** mentioned in the rake task when I call the **rake office:send_reminder** from the terminal.

Comment: @ARK I found my mistake. I didnt turn on the sidekiq server.

Answer (score 2):

I found my mistake. I didn't turn on the sidekiq server.